# Dates don't compare properly - Power Bi

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, filtering

I would like to SUMX my Employees Wages, but without Employees who have any sickness record, in which selected date is. So, if Employee was sick from March 3rd to March 5th and Selected Date is March 4th, we don't take that Employee into an account.

*That's How I Get A CurrentDay From Slicer:*

[image: That's How I Get A CurrentDay From Slicer]

*That's How I Was Trying To At Least Sum Rows, In Which CurrentDay Is Before EndDate of Sickness Record*:

[image: That's How I Was Trying To At Least Sum Rows, In Which CurrentDay Is Before EndDate of Sickness Record]

And all I get is... The number of TOTAL rows in my sickness records table:
[image: And all I get is... The number of TOTAL rows in my sickness records table.]

How can I filter that table, to get a valid result?

Comment: Do you have `[StartDate]` column? How the table is linked to Calendar?  Can you add a sample table and result sample?

Comment: I have that column, but right now I JUST wanted to check one column, because nothing is working properly. It's linked to a calendar table (date column) with *:1 (many to one). 
So, my sickness records look like this:
https://pasteboard.co/KQR9HwrLjbyX.png

And columns are changed to a date column in Power Query Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your tables is not clear. So, looking through your code you can try following:

```
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        table -- ALL(table) as variant, depends on your report ect.
        ,table[StartDate] <= SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]) & table[EndDate] >= SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date])
```

)

Comment: What do you mean by "not clear"? What can I improve/change?